# Sortable Interface for different types of components react dnd

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, react-dnd

I was going through react dnd's documentation on creating a sortable example where I found a working example at http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples-sortable-simple.html.
I have use case similar to this where my list contains items of different types.

Is adding a common wrapper component over each type of list item, considered a good design option? This will help me retain the present architecture and not mess up things.

[image: Something on below line]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentions it's possible to have an array of types for the [DropTarget](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drop-target.html) but only one type for the [DragSource](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-source.html).

Comment: Yes the above documentation points out clearly that we can have multiple drop targets but my concern is more over code duplication and the mess it will create since each component will have an array of DropTargets. If I have a common wrapper component , I can have just a common DragSource and DropTarget which can be used easily

Comment: there should be no duplication. Imagin you have list component that's dropable " render method return connectDropTarget", each event for the drop can check the drop Type Like so  const ItemType = monitor.getItemType();
            if (ItemType == "Box") {